# jQuery UI Dialog Content being shown in button section

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I have been working with jQuery dialog for a while, and the problem I am getting now is kind of strange.

jQuery version: 1.7.1
jQuery UI version: 1.8.18

```
<!-- Generic Dialog Box -->
<div id="dialog" style="display:none;position:absolute;"></div>
```

jQuery code:

```
$('.class_to_find').each(function(){
    //$('#dialog').append($(this).css({position:"absolute"}));
    $('#dialog').append("<p>Adding a line.</p>");
});
$('#dialog').dialog({
    //autoOpen: true,
    show: "explode",
    hide: "explode",
    modal: true,
    title: "Jobs",
    buttons: {
        Done: function() {
            $(this).dialog( "close" );
        }
    },
    close: function(){}
});
$('#dialog').dialog('open');
```

[image]

When the dialog opens, the content shows up underneath where the content usually shows up.  it shows up in the button pane.  This is a problem.  I can't figure out why it is doing this.  Does anyone know why?

Here is a JSFiddle which exposes the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/8Lj8m/1/

Thanks!

Comment: can you provide your code in fiddler.

Comment: Try html() instead of append()

Comment: can u share your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: Here is a JSfiddle which replicates the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/8Lj8m/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove dialog div style property `position:absolute;` and see if that is what you need.